# Cannot get aspect ration to 1 with simple Graphics

Tags: graphics

I am learning Mathematica and doing a simple animation project which animates the harmonic motion of a pendulum.  For some reason, I cannot get the simplest thing to work -- the aspect ratio for my pendulum graph will not go to 1.  I have whittled my code down to something extremely simple that illustrates my problem:

`Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, -.5}}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

[image: Output of the code above]

Comment: `AspectRatio -> 1` produces a square graphic. Perhaps you wanted `AspectRatio -> Automatic` ?

Comment: Perhaps what you wanted is `AspectRatio -> 1/2`? This is because the y range is one half of the x range.

Comment: Simon Woods:  Setting the aspect ratio to automatic did set it to 1.  However, the graphic is actually embedded inside a GraphicsGrid and I need all the graphics' aspect ratios set to 1 so that the animations align.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to equalize the width and height of the screen image, in addition to the aspect ratio, as follows:

```
g = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, -.5}}], Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 1];
ImageDimensions[g]
```

> Out: {600, 609}

```
g1 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, -.5}}], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
ImageDimensions[g1]
```

[image]

> Out: {500, 500}